# Data entry in selenium multithreaded chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing the multi-threaded ChromeDriver in Selenium. Also, I have a text file containing the login content:

```
Email 1
Email 2
Email 3
Email 4
```

How do I run 4 threads (i.e., 4 Chrome windows) at the same time? The data in the text file should be divided equally between these 4 threads and should not contain duplicates.

Here is my multi-threaded code snippet:

```
   private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               var login = "mail.txt";

               var getloginrd = File.ReadLines(login).ToList();

               int countloginrd = getloginrd.Count();

               Random getrdlogin = new Random();

               int rdlogin = getrdlogin.Next(0, countloginrd);

               string getlogin = getloginrd.Skip(rdlogin).First();

               Console.WriteLine(getlogin);


               int iThread = 0, maxThread = 4;

               for (int i = 0; i < maxThread;)
               {
                   if (iThread < maxThread)
                   {
                       Interlocked.Increment(ref iThread);
                       i++;
                       new Thread(() =>
                       {
                           LoginOneThread();
                           Interlocked.Decrement(ref iThread);
                       }).Start();

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Thread.Sleep(100);
                   }
               }

               while (iThread > 0)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(500);
               }
           }
```

```
     private void LoginOneThread()
            {
             var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

                driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                //Mở chrome

                var drivery = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());


                  drivery.Url = "http://phamnhi.net";

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);

                        IWebElement elementuser = drivery.FindElementByName("username");

                        elementuser.SendKeys(getlogin);

                        IWebElement elemenlogin = drivery.FindElementById("login-signin");

                        elemenlogin.Click();

                        break;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {

                    }

            }
```

Comment: I want to run 4 threads (ie 4 chrome windows) at the same time ... the data in the text file will be divided equally between these 4 threads and not be duplicated.

Comment: I have run 4 threads and want to use the data in the text file to divide them evenly among those 4 streams. The code above I wrote when running 4 duplicate input data streams ...

I want:
stream 1: email 1
stream 2: email 2
stream3: email 3
stream 4: email 4

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the test framework you are using and what kind of `Parallel` support the framework provides. I see you have tagged this with C# - are you using `NUnit by any chance?

Comment: yes I have used NUnit. Can you give me an example? I'm new so I don't know much yet

Comment: When I run, all 4 streams enter data as "mail1". I want them to not overlap.

Comment: Are you using a very old c#? It seems like you would want Tasks for this.